# React (CORS with Keycloak): no header set or header set twice, no OPTIONS call but HTTP status (cancelled)

Tags: java, reactjs, rest, cors, keycloak

I'm working on a react frontend using REST to communicate with a JAVA backend (Thorntail microservice), secured by Keycloak. Using GET and POST there's no problem, but trying to DELETE returns different errors depending on my settings. My default CorsFilter.java file has no settings:

```
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class CorsFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
                       ContainerResponseContext responseContext) { 
    }
}
```

My React REST function:

```
static deleteCourier = function (origin, courierNumber, endpoint, data, requestListener) {
    keycloak.updateToken(5).then(function () {
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("DELETE", HTTP_SCHEME + "://" + backendUrl + endpoint + "/" + origin + "/" + courierNumber);
        request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer' + keycloak.token);
        request.send();
    }).catch(function () {
        console.log('Failed to refresh the token, or the session has expired');
        keycloak.init({onLoad: 'login-required'}).success(function (authenticated) {
            if (authenticated) {
                Rest.deleteCourier(origin, courierNumber, endpoint, data, requestListener);
            } else {
                console.log('kc not authenticated');
            }
        }).error(function () {
            console.log('kc init failed');
        });
    }).then(function () {
        Rest.updateData(data, requestListener, endpoint)
    });
};
```

Calling the REST API of the backend:

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.OPTIONS;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/device")
public class DeviceEndpoint {   

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{origin}/{courierNumber}")
    public Response delete(
            @PathParam("origin") String origin,
            @PathParam("courierNumber") String courierNumber) {
        try {
            deviceBF.removeCourier(origin, courierNumber);
        } catch (PhoenixClientException e) {
            return Response.ok(new WebApplicationException(e)).build();
        }
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

In Keycloak "Web Origins" is set to "*".

Using this setup GET and POST work as intended. When trying to delete a device the network tab in my browser shows me as status: "(canceled)" and (Copied as fetch from Googles Chrome):

> fetch("http://192.168.0.66:8282/auth/realms/customer/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=mystique&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.0.66%3A8080%2Fmystique%2Frest%2Fdevice%2Fdts%2Fd&state=22a1dba6-e12e-4852-8cba-0f86a4799d4f&login=true&scope=openid", {"credentials":"omit","referrer":"http://localhost:3000/","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade","body":null,"method":"DELETE","mode":"cors"});

And the console output is:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.0.66:8080/mystique/rest/device/dts/d' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

GET and POST requests send OPTIONS request before the real request. In this case no such OPTIONS request is sent.

When i put a console output to my REST API I can see that it is not called. But the path should be ok. Tested the REST API via Postman and everything worked.

If I modify the CorsFilter.java file and add for example:

```
    responseContext.getHeaders().add(
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
```

... the browser console shows to me:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.0.66:8080/mystique/rest/websocket-auth/token' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:3000, http://localhost:3000', but only one is allowed.

I've searched my code and also all my config files for the second entry and found nothing. I don't have any clue where it's from.

Adding the following to the CorsFilter.java seems to have no effect.

```
responseContext.getHeaders().add(
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
```

In addition to the previously described behaviour the device, the courier is belonging to, is deleted. I'm not sure if this is corresponding to the problem with CORS or if it is a single problem. Changing a devices' data without deleting a courier (which is also done via REST) works as intended. But with the deletion of a courier before the update deletes my device.

I hope anybody can help me with this.

Comment: Just to confirm: is your code firing `DELETE` request to your Keycloak? Also it looks your app (http://192.168.0.66:8080/) doesn't provide correct CORS response for frontend (http://localhost:3000)

Comment: @Jan Garaj As far as i understand it Keycloak is just for the authentication. The DELETE is fired to the REST API of the java backend using Keycloak to authenticate the user/browser to the backend. I could imagine that Keycloak is not permitting the browser to send a DELETE request, but thats just a guess based on various articles i read, the "fetch" message from browser and that the REST API is not called from within the browser. I don't know how to test it or even set up the DELETE method in Keycloak.

Comment: You are mixing a few errors here. Disable any auth/keycloak and fix CORS issues in your code frontend<->backend communication first. `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.0.66:8080/mystique/rest/websocket-auth/token' from origin 'http://localhost:3000'` is definitely not a problem with the Keycloak.

Comment: @JanGaraj Ok. I'll try this. But this will take some time. It seems that it's not that easy to deactivate Keycloak. I'll tell you when I have any news. Thanks so far.

Comment: @JanGaraj It seems that I managed to deactivate Keycloak. After this I also had to add headers in CorsFilter.java ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "content-type"). That was all to enable the correct behaviour of the REST API. For me it looks like all the problems came from Keycloak!?!?
PS: The deletion of devices was my fault, mixed up a few variables.